# Null reference in my column name in the event of combo box SelectedIndexChanged on closing form

Tags: c#

I am using combobox to display the items when i select the the item it displays the ID of that item in textbox below of it, i have written the code inside the selected change index event, when i execute the form and close that form without doing any thing in the form it show me Object reference not set to an instance of an object on my string query 
 my code is given below:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    namespace TinyErp
    { 
public partial class frmaddprod : Form
{
    public frmaddprod()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void productsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.productsBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.orderMachineDataSet);

    }


    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.OrderMachineConnectionString);
    string strgetsupp;


    private void frmaddprod_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'orderMachineDataSet.Suppliers' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.suppliersTableAdapter.Fill(this.orderMachineDataSet.Suppliers);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'orderMachineDataSet.Products' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.productsTableAdapter.Fill(this.orderMachineDataSet.Products);

        //string strgetsupp = "select supplier_id from Suppliers where supplier_company='" + ((DataRowView)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Row["supplier_company"].ToString() + "'";
        //conn.Open();
        //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strgetsupp, conn);
        //SqlDataReader read;
        //read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        //read.Read();
        //int sid = int.Parse(read["supplier_id"].ToString());
        //read.Close();
        //conn.Close();
        //supplier_idTextBox.Text = sid.ToString();

    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        strgetsupp = "select supplier_id from Suppliers where supplier_company='" + ((DataRowView)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Row["supplier_company"].ToString() + "'";
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strgetsupp, conn);
        SqlDataReader read;
        read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        read.Read();
        int sid = int.Parse(read["supplier_id"].ToString());
        supplier_idTextBox.Text = sid.ToString();
        read.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }

    private void productsDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void frmaddprod_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
 }
 }
```

Comment: do you know which line crashes?

Comment: strgetsupp = "select supplier_id from Suppliers where supplier_company='" + ((DataRowView)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Row["supplier_company"].ToString() + "'";
this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if comboBox1.SelectedItem is null before executing anything else

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(comboBox1.SelectedItem==null)
            return;

        strgetsupp = "select supplier_id from Suppliers where supplier_company='" + ((DataRowView)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Row["supplier_company"].ToString() + "'";
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strgetsupp, conn);
        SqlDataReader read;
        read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        read.Read();
        int sid = int.Parse(read["supplier_id"].ToString());
        supplier_idTextBox.Text = sid.ToString();
        read.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: it was showing the error because for some reason it's trying to call comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged when the form is closed.  I'm not sure why.  Evidently, when you close the form the SelectedItem is null, and the does not understand null.Row